# IBM Db2 - How to monitor progres of ALTER TABLE command?

Tags: db2, alter-table, db2-luw, db2-11.5

On IBM Db2 v11.5.8.0 Linux/x86_64 I have to add several columns in pretty big table with ALTER TABLE command.

On test database now it takes for more then an hour, but I don't have any info how long will it take to finish. Is there a way I can monitor the progress of ALTER TABLE command on database?

I have checked and there is no other database connection executing any other command/SQL.

Regards

Comment: The size of a table doesn't matter - existing data pages are not changed on ALTER TABLE ADD COLUMN. Try to look into the db2diag.log file on the server for suspicious records appeared there. You may monitor various counter increase from another connection for this application handle with the `mon_get_connection` & `mon_get_agent` function.